# dell R710 / R620 power-supply broken after firmware update

Tags: dell, update, firmware, power-supply-unit

We datet up the firmware on a dell R710 and some weeks later on a DELL R620. In both cases the firmware update on one of the two power supplies failed and it didn't work any more (amber flashing).

With the premier support we tried to revive them and finally we got new PSUs in both cases. Neither the premier support nor newsgroups could tell us how to prevent that in the future.

Now we are facing a new update.

Is there any way to prevent this?

**Edit**
Power-supplies in DELL Poweredge servers have a firmware. Here is the log of a failing update on the first power supply. After that it had to be replaced.

```
2015-01-05T18:40:51-0600    SUP0538 Unable to update [PSU-1] PWR SPLY,750WP,RDNT,FLX, F0.00.99, A01.
2015-01-05T18:55:32-0600    PSU0006 Power supply 1 is incorrectly configured.
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the update, as you are on support no worry, especially if you got two powersupply. Be aware that dell usually write what the change is, so you can weight the need for the update.

Comment: Usually we only update critical firmware. (Paradoxically the update for the delta psu was former `critical` and now it is only `optional`). The major problem is, that another weekend appointment with our customer is needed.

Comment: @boboes The only way I see possible to prevent another shutdown in case it go bad is to switch the PS to another server with the same, but a server that can be shut off. You could be able to do the update off the prod, as you reswitch back the PS after they had been upgraded

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to me on a R620 and the Dell tech said that the P/S firmware update can take up to 15 Minutes and durrning that time your server will shut down and be off. If you pull the plugs or try to boot the server durring that time you can corrupt the firmware. It would be nice to be warned about that.

Comment: Finally it looks like as you described. The DELL support wasn't sure about that but recommended to wait till 1/2 hour and do not unplug the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not very common, though not unheard of... It seems quite odd you had one fail in two different systems in this manner though.

As others suggested, check the release notes for the updates before applying if you're wary. If it's not a critical update, you may not need concern yourself with proceeding. But if you're under warranty, what's the harm in just replacing more hardware if it happens again?

Most never update PSU FW from my experience, and updates don't seem to have a huge impact on failure rate.